# How to propagate `Result` through `.max_by_key()`

Tags: rust

I have a function `float_or_err(i)` that takes an integer and returns either a float or an error. I want to write a function that takes an array of integers and returns the one for which `float_or_err(i)` is greatest, or propagates the error if `float_or_err()` errors on any of the `i`s.

Now, I have read [Using max_by_key on a vector of floats [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37127209/using-max-by-key-on-a-vector-of-floats) and I understand why Rust doesn't implement a total ordering on floats, and I have decided to use the `ordered_float` crate instead of `f64` to impose a total ordering on the results of `float_or_err()`.

However, that question does not address the case where the argument to `.max_by_key()` is a closure that returns a `Result<OrderedFloat<f64>, _>`, as in the following example:

```rust
use ordered_float::OrderedFloat;

fn main() {}

enum ErrorKind {
    ValidationError
}

// Function of `i` that normally returns an f64 but sometimes has an error
fn float_or_err(i: &isize) -> Result<OrderedFloat<f64>, ErrorKind> {
    if i % 5 == 0 {
        return Err(ErrorKind::ValidationError);
    }
    else {
        return Ok(OrderedFloat(3.14));
    }
}

// Given a vec of integers `i`, find the one for which `float_or_err(i)` is 
// largest. If any of those integers `i` yields an error in `float_or_err(i)`,
// return the error.
fn max_by_float_or_err(v: Vec<isize>) -> Option<&isize> {
    return v.iter().max_by_key(|i| float_or_err(i));
}
```

The compiler does not accept the second-to-last line, because

```
the trait bound `ErrorKind: Ord` is not satisfied
the trait `Ord` is implemented for `Result<T, E>`
```

OK, looks like I need to do something like

```rust
impl Ord for Result<OrderedFloat<f64>, ErrorKind> {
    // ...
}
```

(where I order first by the float, then use the ErrorKind as a tiebreaker.)

But the compiler won't let me implement `Ord` for a type that I didn't create:

```
`Result` is not defined in the current craterustcE0117
main.rs(9, 1): original diagnostic
only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for types defined outside of the crate
```

Actually, my first intuition is to write:

```
fn argmax_by_float_or_err(v: Vec<isize>) -> Option<&isize> {
    return v.iter().max_by_key(|i| float_or_err(i)?);
}
```

But this doesn't compile either, because you can't use the question mark operator inside of a closure. I have read [Alternatives for using the question mark operator inside a map function closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62687455/alternatives-for-using-the-question-mark-operator-inside-a-map-function-closure), where the suggested solution is to just to move the question mark to the end of the chain, but that solution is particular to the function in question, where the reduce op is `.sum()` instead of `.max_by_key()`, and `.sum()` is implemented natively for Result. This is not the case for `.max_by_key()` (and many other reduce ops).

- In the context of the `max_by_float_or_err()` function defined above, how can I propogate errors from `float_or_err()`?
- I am looking for a solution that uses `.max_by_key()` (or at least another reduce op) instead of rewriting the body as a for loop.

---

*Edit:* I also read [How do I implement a trait I don't own for a type I don't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413201/how-do-i-implement-a-trait-i-dont-own-for-a-type-i-dont-own), which suggests something like:

```rust
struct MyResult(Result<OrderedFloat<f64>, ErrorKind>);

impl Ord for MyResult {
    // ...
}
```

This solution is unsatisfactory because instances of `MyResult` don't seem to inherit all the methods associated with normal `Result`s. For example, I cannot write:

```rust
let my_result: OrderedFloat<f64> = float_or_err(-1).unwrap_or_default(6.28);
```

Comment: By the way, the signature `(v: Vec<isize>) -> Option<&isize>` won't work since it would attempt to return a reference to a value `v` that would be destroyed at the end of the function. You probably want `v: &[isize]` (as the answers assume) or `.into_iter()` + `Option<isize>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you are looking to short-circuit on an `Err`, which the `max_by_key` function is not capable of. I would probably make this in a for loop, but this is possible using a short-circuiting method such as [`try_fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_fold).

```rs
pub fn max_by_float_or_err(v: &[isize]) -> Result<Option<&isize>, ErrorKind> {
    let Some((first, rest)) = v.split_first() else { return Ok(None) };
    let initial = (first, float_or_err(first)?);

    let max: Result<&isize, ErrorKind> = rest
        .iter()
        .try_fold(initial, |(acc, acc_key), item| {
            let item_key = float_or_err(item)?;
            if acc_key > item_key {
                Ok((acc, acc_key))
            } else {
                Ok((item, item_key))
            }
        })
        .map(|(item, _key)| item);

    Some(max).transpose()
}
```

In the future, this would be slightly simpler with [`try_reduce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_reduce)

Comment: How would I set the value of `initial` dynamically if I have a filter between `.iter()` and `.try_fold()`? Is there a way to do this without creating two iters? I think this convinces me that I should just use a for loop :)

Comment: @Max You can either apply the filter to the first element before passing it into `filter`, or you can create the iterator with filter first and use `next` instead of `split_first`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generic version of `max_by_key()` that propagates errors:

```
fn try_max_by_key<I, F, K, E>(mut iter: I, mut f: F) -> Result<Option<I::Item>, E>
where
    I: Iterator,
    F: FnMut(&I::Item) -> Result<K, E>,
    K: Ord,
{
    let Some(mut curr) = iter.next() else { return Ok(None) };
    let mut curr_key = f(&curr)?;

    for next in iter {
        let next_key = f(&next)?;
        if next_key > curr_key {
            curr = next;
            curr_key = next_key;
        }
    }

    Ok(Some(curr))
}
```